# Unable to make sense of injected text

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've just installed a new plugin that adds a gallery for product variations (Additional Variation Images Gallery for WooCommerce). Now that I'm testing it, I notice that whenever a variation is selected, text elements are injected on screen. It also shows up in the code itself when I open "inspect element."

I'm trying to figure out what it could be coming from so I can remove it via CSS. But I've got no idea what it is or how to target it. Can anyone help me out?

[image: On-screen text]
[image: "Elements"]

Answer (score 0):

Report this to the plugin author. Maybe it's their bug, or maybe they'll be able to tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I have. Their response time seems to be about 2 weeks though. Normally I can figure out these things and fix them myself. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: My guess is that your embed code/configuration isnt good, or that the content contains those characters. I would review those parts. Try removing that part and making sure that you dont have those chars. That way you will be certain the problem is either in your embed configuration or the plugin. Maybe even look for alternate.plugin.

Comment: make sure your embed code contains valid html, where all tags are properly closed.